# Selecting dropdown menu option with Selenium - dropdown only appears after typing search query into box

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select

I'm hoping someone may be able to help me with selecting a pop-up dropdown menu option using selenium in python in Google Colab.

The URL is: http://www.neotroptree.info/data/countrysearch

The website allows a search by geography. Once you type a search term into the Domain box (here I'm using the search term 'Cerrado'), a dropdown menu appears with Domain name matches. If you click the Cerrado dropdown option, the webpage will bring up all the data results from that search.

The ultimate goal of this is to scrape the text info from those data results (e.g., Latitude, Longitude, etc). As there is no unique URL associated with the Domain search, the only way I can think to get the URL for the search is using python & selenium to navigate to the results webpage.

So far I have been able to set the webdriver, get the original URL and send my search term ('Cerrado') to the Domain input box.

```
# Install required modules/packages
!pip install selenium -qq
!pip install beautifulsoup4 -qq
!apt install chromium-chromedriver -qq
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

```
# Set webdriver as Chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

```
# Direct to webpage and search for the Cerrado 
driver.get('http://www.neotroptree.info/data/countrysearch')
driver.maximize_window()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#domain")))
driver.find_element_by_name('domain_s').send_keys('Cerrado')
```

After this, I'm unsure of how to interact with the dropdown menu that should have popped up after typing in the search term. I've tried using Select and the dropdown menu id, with error messages cropping up.

```
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-20'))
```

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-1329b8077ff2> in <module>()
----> 1 dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-20'))

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="ui-id-20"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

This is what is displayed when I click on the dropdown menu manually in Chrome to inspect it:

```
li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-20" tabindex="-1">Cerrado</li
```

Any advice on how to select something from the pop-up dropdown menu would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a regular dropdown and for your field is triggered by typing behavior, and you need to emulate the typing from code, here is a solution.

```
domain_string = 'Cerrado'
domain_element = driver.find_element_by_name('domain_s')
for char in domain_string:
    domain_element.send_keys(char)
    time.sleep(0.3)

driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-menu-item').click()
```